# Association information not being displayed in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, associations

The current_user has one quiz which has questions 1 through 5, entered here:

```
<%= form_for @quiz do |f| %>
            <div class="field"> <!-- question 1 name -->
                <%= f.label :q1, "What will be your first question?", :class => "edit_labels", :maxlength => 10 %>
                <%= f.text_field :q1, :placeholder => "Question 1",  :style => "text-align: center" %>
            </div>
,,,,
```

created in the controller this takes place as

```
def landing
@quiz = Quiz.new
end
```

in the Quizzes controller:

```
def edit
@quiz = Quiz.find(params:[id])
end

def create
@quiz = current_user.build_quiz(quiz_params)
if @quiz.save
  flash[:success] = "Updated"
  redirect_to '/'
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def quiz_params
  params.require(:quiz).permit(:q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :q5)
end

 def show
 @quizzes = Quiz.all
 end
```

Now, when I try to display the users:

```
 /users/index.html.erb
 <%= render @users %>
```

and in the partial:

```
  /users/_user.html.erb
   <%= user.username %>
   <%= user.quiz.q1 %>
   etc...more fields
```

It works producing usernames, but it does not for the quiz.q1
Specifically, I get

```
undefined method `q1' for nil:NilClass
```

but if I type

```
<%= current_user.quiz.q1 %>
```

in 'welcome/landing.html.erb', it produces the correct result.

I would appreciate some help very much. Thank you.

Comment: Hello again helpisgood. maybe you should check the user first `user.quiz.nil?` if true then dont print otherwise print the quiz if user created a quiz.

Comment: @Marv-C When I do that, it shows "false" for the users that DO have quizzes, and true for the ones that don't (so this should be correct)

Comment: oh should be `unless` not `if`

Comment: @Marv-C Ahhhhhh. What it was: It was trying to display admin's quiz (the first user) but it was not created and so it popped the error. Thanks man.